# D365 Countdown Timer

Tags: timer, countdowntimer, x++, dynamics-365

I made a countdown timer in D365, how can I get the timer to run in real time without hanging the form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwygL.png)

It executes once when I press the start button at the moment...

I tried different loops, sleep, timer control, making a button spam method, nothing works without making the form hang.

Comment: Issue is probably that whatever was tried was executing on the same thread that the form runs. x++ does not really have the concept of threading. For this case, an extensible control might be the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/user-interface/build-extensible-control